# GraphQL Apollo query options do not take defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm using query options to pass dynamic variables for my query but it seems that if I set `defaultProps`, graphql is unable to pick up the props value.

My code as below:

```
Page.defaultProps = {
   startDate: moment().hour(15).toISOString(),
   endDate: moment().add(1).hour(3).toISOString(),
};


export default compose(graphql(myQuery, { options: (props: IPageProps) => ({ variables: { range: { start: props.startDate, end: props.endDate }}}))(Page);
```

Logging out props show that the defaultProps take time to be actually included when the component loads, and the variables will always become `{ startDate: undefined, endDate: undefined }`

Is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1):

That's tricky. The easiest thing would be just to declare the defaults twice:

```
const DEFAULT_START = moment().hour(15).toISOString()
const DEFAULT_END = moment().add(1).hour(3).toISOString()

Page.defaultProps = {
   startDate: DEFAULT_START,
   endDate: DEFAULT_END,
}

const options = ({ startDate: start = DEFAULT_START, endDate: end = DEFAULT_END }) => ({ variables: { range: { start, end } } })

export default compose(graphql(myQuery, { options })(Page);
```

If you don't need to reference `startDate` or `endDate` outside of the query, doing it this way would mean you could skip including them as `defaultProps` altogether.

Comment: this actually makes sense, i ended up wrapping the component with another higher order component, and passing props to it. good suggestion though!